# jquery stop form submisson on false condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am validating a duplicate value through ajax. if a duplicate is found then it alerts with an error but does not stop on submission.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#admno").on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var oadmno = $("#oadmno").val();
    var admno = $("#admno").val();
    if (oadmno != admno) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "chkduplicateadmino.php",
        data: $("#admno").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          if (data > 0) {
            $("#admno")
              .closest(".form-group")
              .addClass("has-warning");
            toastr.error("", "Duplicate admission no found", {
              positionClass: "toast-bottom-right",
              preventDuplicates: true
            });
            $("#admno").focus();

            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you are asking. Do you mean that even the form is being submitted? If so, can you post the code for the form submit handler?

Comment: on simply clicking the submit button it is posting the values but according to the code it must not submit the values of form .

Comment: Where is your `clicking the submit button` ?

Comment: where is the check for duplicates in the shared code? If oadmno is not equal to admno, it sends an ajax request ... else it does nothing. Am I missing to understand something here?

Comment: First it is cheking if user is submitting the same data if not then it is sending the data to the checksuplicate.php for finding whether user is posting duplicate value present in db . That code is working  fine what I have written in checkduplicate.php. I just need to freeze the form submit button if duplicate adminno is found from database.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and also `checkduplicate.php` JQuery Code here to see how to handling the submit event.